# Android application stops working when i try to retrieve data from database

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my code and Log cat.
How can I resolve the issue?
I want to make TextViews at runtime using subject name as the text.
As soon as I click on the update attendance button, the application stops working.

SqliteDatabase.java

```
package com.example.attendancemanager2;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SqliteDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    static int a=1;
    public SqliteDatabase(Context context) {
       super(context,"SqliteDatabase" , null, a++);
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("create table AttendanceDatabase (Id int ,Subject text not null unique,Num int,Den int )");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void addData(int Id,String sub,int num,int den)
    {
        database=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("Id",Id);
        contentValues.put("Subject",sub);
        contentValues.put("Num",num);
        contentValues.put("Den",den);
        database.insert("AttendanceDatabase", null,contentValues);
    }
    public Cursor showData() {
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor=database.query("AttendanceDatabase",new String[]{"Id","Subject","Num","Den"} , null,null,null,null,null);
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Activity2.java

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private static final int MY_BUTTON = 9000,MY_BUTTON2 = 9002;
    static int id=0;
    LinearLayout ll;
    SqliteDatabase db2;
    Cursor cursor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.design2);
        db2=new SqliteDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout5);
        cursor=db2.showData();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            int x=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Id"));
            String str1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Username"));
            int y=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Num"));
            int z=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Den"));
            ++i;    
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Row retrieved"+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            //textView.setText(str1);
            //textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                //  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            textView.setId(++id);
            ll.addView(textView);
            cursor.moveToNext();
            --i;
        }
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("Back");
        b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        b.setId(++id);
        ll.addView(b);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);       
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

}
```

```
07-15 23:50:42.076: I/dalvikvm(866): threadid=3: reacting to   signal 3
07-15 23:50:42.316: I/dalvikvm(866): Wrote stack traces to  '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-15 23:50:42.436: D/gralloc_goldfish(866): Emulator without GPU  emulation detected.
07-15 23:50:44.847: D/AndroidRuntime(866): Shutting down VM
07-15 23:50:44.847: W/dalvikvm(866): threadid=1: thread exiting  with uncaught exception (group=0x409bf1f8)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.attendancemanager2/com.example.attendancemanager2.Acti vity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at  com.example.attendancemanager2.SqliteDatabase.showData(SqliteDatabase.java:38)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at com.example.attendancemanager2.Activity2.onCreate(Activity2.java:28)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     ... 11 more
07-15 23:50:45.266: I/dalvikvm(866): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-15 23:50:45.286: I/dalvikvm(866): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-15 23:50:45.416: I/dalvikvm(866): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-15 23:50:45.426: I/dalvikvm(866): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

This is the Main Activity

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  OnClickListener{
    private static final int MY_BUTTON = 9000,MY_BUTTON2 = 9002;
    static int id=0;
    LinearLayout ll;
    SqliteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.design);
        db=new SqliteDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("Add a subject");
        b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        b.setId(MY_BUTTON);
        ll.addView(b);
        Button b2 = new Button(this);
        b2.setText("Update Attendance");
        b2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        b2.setId(MY_BUTTON2);
        ll.addView(b2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class);
                startActivity(i);   
                }
                });
        b.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final EditText editText=new EditText(this);
        editText.setHint("Subject Name");
        editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        editText.setId(id++);
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Add to DB");
        btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btn.setId(id++);
        ll.addView(btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db.addData(id,editText.getText().toString(),0,0);

                }
                });
        ll.addView(editText);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The log clearly shows a NPE:

> 07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>            07-15 23:50:44.865: E/AndroidRuntime(866):     at  com.example.attendancemanager2.SqliteDatabase.showData(SqliteDatabase.java:38)

And it seems like you're trying to call `showData` before you call `addData`, and thus your `database` variable is still NULL.

Comment: How do i remove the error?even after adding data first the app closes after clicking on the update attendance button.